Next 14 middleware protecting signin page don't work when authenticated
I want to protect the login page URL: http://localhost:3000/authentication/signin when the user is authenticated. However, in my middleware, when I have access and refresh, I want to redirect the user to the dashboard component, but it won't work. The console is also not logging when I render http://localhost:3000/authentication/signin, but it does log when in the dashboard component. What is the best approach for middleware to block the signin component when the user is authenticated?

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { DASHBOARD, REGISTER, SIGN_IN } from './app/utils/constants';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    console.log("Request-- >", request.url);

    const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;


    const isPublicPath = path === SIGN_IN || path === REGISTER;

    const access = request.cookies.get('access')?.value;
    const refresh = request.cookies.get('refresh')?.value;

    console.log("PATH", path);
    console.log("isPublicPath", isPublicPath);

    console.log("access", access);
    console.log("refresh", refresh);

    if (isPublicPath && access && refresh) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(DASHBOARD, request.nextUrl))
    }

    if (!isPublicPath && !access && !refresh) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(SIGN_IN, request.nextUrl))
    }

    return NextResponse.next();

}


// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/dashboard/:path*"
    ]
};


I guess you have a missing path in your config.matcher, you need to add the path for the sign in URL.

yeah absolutely, thanks @grekier

not working your middleware in login page because not start with /dashboard your login page pathname and your middleware config run in every page who start pathname with /dashboard;
to run middleware in every page, you can remove your config constant or use bottom code.
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/dashboard/:path*",
        "/authentication/:path*"
    ]
};

